# Intersection of principal ideals in convergent power series ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, power-series, ideals

I am wondering about the following problem in the ring of convergent power series $\mathbb{C}\{x,y\}$:
Assume that you have primary ideals $q_1,...,q_n$ with the radical ideals $\sqrt{q_1} = (g_1),..., \sqrt{q_n} = (g_n)$ generated by irreducible polynomials $g_i \in \mathbb{C}\{x,y\}$.

In a proof that I am currently writing, I want to use that $q_1 \cap ... \cap q_n = (g_1^{p_1}...g_n^{p_n})$ for some natural numbers $p_1,...,p_n$. Nevertheless, I can not see and prove why this has to hold.

Can someone give me a hint/help me?